# Principal IsInRole look up by group name fails, by SID Works C#

Tags: c#, windows-identity

I am surprised that I cannot look up Windows group membership by the group name.

I can use 
    UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups();
But I aparently **cannot** use
    Httpcontext.CurrentUser.IsInRole

to look up the group membership by name to determine if the current user is in a group.

```
  var groups = UserPrincipal.Current.GetGroups();

  var groupNames = groups.Select(x => x.SamAccountName);
  var check0 = groupNames.Contains("pgXbCreateScanDefn"); //works but is not the way by supporting classes currently check.

  //this is how my supporting classes expect to check membership
  var principal = HttpContext.Current.User;
  var check = principal.IsInRole("pgXbCreateScanDefn");   //expected to be true but is not

  //while this works, I would have to translate the user friendly names to SIDs. 
  var check2 = principal.IsInRole("S-1-5-21-4052565669-1266607236-977642746-1013");  //is true as expected,
```

I was able to do this in the past.  Is this no longer supported?

Comment: Are you in a .NET Core application? Or is this on the .NET Framework?

Comment: It's a .NET Framework ASP.NET application.  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same thing at the moment.